# Handling gzip compression in Nancy/Owin

Tags: asp.net, owin, nancy, topshelf

We are developing backend API's using Nancy. Other than hosting it using IIS, we are self-hosting it using Owin. Since Owin does not handle gzip compression automatically (as IIS does), we need to introduce a middleman to handle response/request compression or de-compression. Are there any libraries available already? If there is no libraries available, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Here is a link to an open source project.  https://github.com/Thorium/Owin.Compression

Answer (score 2):

```
    using System.IO.Compression;

  protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        pipelines.AfterRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(AddGZip);
    }


private void AddGZip(NancyContext context)
    {
        if ((!context.Response.ContentType.Contains("application/json")) || !context.Request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Any(
               x => x.Contains("gzip")) || !CompressResponse(context.Request.Url.ToString())) return;
        var jsonData = new MemoryStream();

        context.Response.Contents.Invoke(jsonData);
        jsonData.Position = 0;
        context.Response.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip";
        context.Response.Contents = s =>
        {
            var gzip = new GZipStream(s, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
            jsonData.CopyTo(gzip);
            gzip.Close();
        };
    }
```